# min-width is not working in IE for frozen layout

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, layout, cross-browser

I want to make frozen layout in a website template, but I have problem in Internet Explorer.

I make like this

```
<div id="NewsBlock">
    <div id="aboutUs">
        <h1></h1>
        <span class="OpenDayBanner"></span>
        <p>You can replace the paragraph above with some text describing your FAQ system. Here's an example: If you have questions about our web site, our products or our services, there’s a good chance you’ll find the answer here</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

For CSS I make like this

```
div#NewsBlock{
    min-width: 1300px;   //this work for Firefox and chrome
    width:100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 510px;
    background-image:url(../images/aboutstartupbg.png);
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
 }
```

Using the min-width and percentage value for width make the layout frozen in Firefox and Chrome but it doesn't work in IE!! Any suggestions please

Comment: What do you mean by frozen? And what version of IE has that problem?

Comment: I mean when resizing the bower, the layout is still frozen, some of the layout will be hide and the other will be stable.

Comment: The same as stackoverflow layout, try to re-size the browser.

Comment: I think it's called "fixed width layout". Dont seem have the problem in IE9. What IE version are you using? - http://jsfiddle.net/LKaT8/1/

Answer (score 0):

You have to define the [min-width](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_dim_min-width.asp) property of the `<p>` element.

Example:

```
p.myClass {
    min-width: 420px;
   }
```

Comment: And why is that? Will nor the p element inherit the width from the div element which already has a min-width: 1300px ?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is solved by changing the dtd of the HTML to XHTML

```
 <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" ">
```

to

```
   <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org    /TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

   <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a strict doctype, such as `<!DOCTYPE HTML>`, to make sure IE is rendeing correctly.

Also consider adding `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />` to the `<head>`.

Comment: It works with Transitional doc type too. what is the difference between this meta data and this one <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">

Comment: "What is the difference"? Erm... well, everything. It's a completely different `http-equiv`.